# Is there a matrix $A$ such that $rank(A) < rank(A^2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am searching over the $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$ fields. I can think of a simple example the opposite way where the $rank(A) > rank(A^2)$$$\left(\begin{array}{rr}%
0&0\\%
1&0\\%
\end{array}\right)$$ and of course equality has many examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the rank-nullity theorem, this is the same as $\ker A >\ker A^2$. Can this possibly happen?

Comment: This is a nice way to think about it since clearly $\forall x \in null(A)$$$AAx=A\textbf{0} = \textbf{0}$$ so $null(A) \subseteq null(A^2).$

Answer (score 4):

No this is impossible since for matrices $A$ and $B$, the columns of $AB$ are linear combinations of the columns of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

According to rank-nullity theorem- **rank+nullity=number of columns**.

So, obviously here $A$ is a square matrix. Let say $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix. So, $$\rho(A)+\nu(A)=n \ \dots(1)$$
$$\rho(A^2)+\nu(A^2)=n \ \dots(2)$$

Let say, $x\in \mathcal{N}(A)$. So, $Ax=\theta_n \implies A^2x=\theta_n.$ So, $\mathcal{N}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{N}(A^2)$. So, $\nu(A^2)\geq\nu(A).$

This proves that- $\rho(A)\geq\rho(A^2).$